# Installing c++ boost using cygwin: can't find configure file

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries

I'm trying to install Boost for c++. Since I use cygwin (on Windows 7) I follow [these](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#id23) instructions for Unix.

I start by downloading *boost_1_55_0.zip* from sourceforge. The instructions tell me to run `tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_55_0.zip` but this doesn't work (probably because the downloaded file is *.zip* and not *.tar.bz2*; I can't find the latter anywhere to download), so instead I use winrar and unzip it into */usr/local*.

After this the header-only libraries work fine, but I need the ones where a build is necessary.

The instructions tells me to go to the boost folder and run`./configure --help`, but this doesn't work; I get the message `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`. So I locate the file *configure* in the folder */usr/local/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/engine/boehm_gc*, go there and try again, and this time it works: I get the help for *configure*.

I then try to run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/boost_1_55_0 --enable-cplusplus` but get the error message `configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub`. I try it with only one or none of the options too but that doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error tells you, that configure which is a script tried to execute `/bin/sh ./config.sub` but failed. I am not familiar with Cygwin but I suspect you do not have the shell (/bin/sh) installed. Can you execute `/bin/sh --version`?

Comment: @user2799037 Yeah, I get `GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what guide you're following, but to install boost I have done:

```
cd boost
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
./b2 install
```

stop

As report [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/more/getting_started/windows.html):

> If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually
>   running on a POSIX platform and should follow the instructions for
>   getting started on Unix variants. Other command shells, such as
>   MinGW's MSYS, are not supported—they may or may not work.

Comment: That works, thanks! The tutorial I was using was indeed the one for Cygwin that you're linking to there.